# Jackson Converting String to Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, fasterxml

**Link.java**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "rel", "href","method" })
public class Link {

    @JsonProperty("rel")
    private String rel;
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
    @JsonProperty("method")
    private Method method;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

I have this third party class with fasterxml jackson annotations. I can convert a given object into a string using the specified toString() method. Is there any way of using that String to get an object of type Link?

Note: The object itself has an embedded object (which has several more embedded objects) and these too needs to be converted into a Method object from the string itself.

Comment: don't use toString Use jackson ObjectMapper::readValue and ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString

Comment: Use `new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Link.class);`

Comment: @pvpkiran ... although `ToStringBuilder` can be configured to output JSON, which `ObjectMapper` would be able to consume.

Comment: yes you can but there are cases where toString() performs very badly expecially in cases of nested objects and collections.Try printing a map or list with toString and also with ObjectMapper and see the difference

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Just putting the comment by @pvpkiran in an answer.

Use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class from *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind*

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

**Converting from Object to String:**

```
String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(link);
```

**Converting from String to Object:**

```
Link link = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, type)
```

Comment: we can also call like this String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object);

Comment: what if don't know what is the class type?

Comment: Java can't ascertain the class type magically? You can have ton of Classes which could possibly fit it